# linux tar command -t option to show max-depth=1

Tags: linux, tar

A tar.gz file may contain many files and folders, and the folders may, in turn, have a lot of files and folders.

I want to list the contents of the tar.gz file, but only one directory deep.

How can I write this command?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to limit the depth if files going *in* to the archive, or limit the depth of files you extract *out* of the archive?

Comment: `tar -ztf  file.tar.gz`  limit the depth the file show in terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tar` command does not provide a way to do this, but you can filter its output using `grep`:

```
tar tfz file.tar.gz | grep -v '/'
```

or, to add one level more

```
tar tfz file.tar.gz | grep -v '/.*/'
```

or, to add another level of files:

```
tar tfz file.tar.gz | grep -v '/.*/.*/'
```

Comment: see my picture in my question

Comment: I clearly didn't manage to guess what you meant exactly. How about now?

Answer (score 0):

`grep`, `egrep` did not work for me.

`tar -tf <file.tar> | cut -f1-<whatever...> -d\ | uniq` works w/o `-v` optionf or `tar`, where `<file.tar>` is obvious, yet `<whatever...>` depends on the length of the path of the directories archived, e.g. `/home/luser1/his_forgotten_stuff`, `/home/luser2/other_desperate_deadline`, etc.

I suppose a combo of `--no-recurse`, and `--exclude=`  would do a better jobs, yet is beyond and above me to deal w/`glob()`, which I suspect it behaves  distro dependent. :/ :( .